# How to call view in another view but with triggered controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi how could I render one view inside another but with its data...

for example I have view home.ctp, than controller for news, and news.ctp
I want to render in home.ctp news.ctp but first all news has to be selected from database...

I tried this

```
echo $this->elements(../News/news);
```

but there is no selected data to be displayed.. it returns error undefined variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CakePHP cell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) is the right thing to solve such type of problems. In [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) document there is a easy tutorial. you can check it